# Use of 'ever' in a question along with modal could

Tags: word-meaning

> —You create the world of the dream. We bring the subject into that
>   dream and they fill it with their subconscious.
>
> — *How could I ever* acquire enough details to make them think that it's
>   reality

I can't get the point of that usage of `ever`. Is that used to emphasize unclearness of how to make someone think that it's reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read it, it is similar to:

> How could I **possibly** acquire enough details to make them think that it's reality.

So I would go with the definition [ever](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ever) sense 3:

> 3) at all; by any chance; in any way   ⇒ "how can I ever repay you?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Essentially, we can use it to emphasize unclearness how to do something what we're asking about, can we?